Proof of the properties of even\odd multiplicity in polynomial functions
I am self-studying some Pre-Calculus looking forward to learning some Calculus.
Concerning a generic polynomial function $P(x)$, I  have found in every Pre-Calculus book the statement that:

If r is a real zero of $P(x)$ of even multiplicity, the sign of $P(x)$ does not change from one side to the other side of r. Graphically: The graph of $P(x)$ touches (or bounces on) the $x$-axis at r.

If r Is a real zero of $P(x)$ of odd multiplicity, the sign of $P(x)$ changes from one side to the other side of r. Graphically: The graph of $P(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis at r.


I cannot find any proof of this statement.
I can provide the following incomplete argument. If r is a zero of $P(x)$, then we have that $(x - r)^n$ is a factor in $P(x)$. So we have that $P(x)$ = $(x - r)^n$ $Q(x)$, for some $Q$. Now, I suppose (but I am not able to prove!) that:
[#] If we consider $x$ in a small enough neighborhood of r, we have that Q(x) preserves signs.
Now, if [#] holds, then I can easily understand why the statement holds, distinguishing wether n is odd or even. But, to repeat, I am not able to prove [#]. Does it have to do with the continuity and smoothness of polynomial functions (which are calculus notions I am not acquainted yet)?
Thank you.

It's not so much that $Q(x)$ "preserves signs", whatever that means, as that $Q(x)$ has a well defined sign near $r$.  $Q(r)$ can't be $0$, else the root multiplicity would be higher.  So:  argue that it has a constant sign in a neighborhood of $r$ and that this does what you want.

How can I argue for the constancy of the sign in the neighborhood of r?
As far as I understand, the constancy of the sign in the neighborhood of r is something we need to prove 1) and 2). What I am asking is then how we can justify this constancy.

If $Q(r)=c>0$ then, by continuity, there is a neighborhood around $x=r$ in which $Q(x)>\frac c2$, hence positive.  Same argument if $Q(r)=c<0$.    Make sure you understand this...it's true for any continuous function, not just polynomials.

I see. Thank you so much. So as I suspected, it has to do with continuity. I am not acquainted yet with this notion (I am still studying precalculus), but at least now 1) and 2) are less obscure.
